# bulk update in mongoDB with setonInsert

Tags: mongodb, python-2.7, pymongo

I am trying to bulk update in mongoDB. If a document is inserted then 'es_mysql_id' feild value will be assigned as a serial number else document will be updated

```
    bulk = db[product_line].initialize_unordered_bulk_op()
    for doc in product_data_list:

        bulk.find({'pdpData.landingPageUrl': doc['pdpData']['landingPageUrl']}).upsert().update({
            {
                '$setOnInsert':{
                        'es_mysql_id': serial_number
                }
            }
            ,doc})
        serial_number+=1

    bulk.execute()
```

this is giving me error as

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

what I am doing wrong in this

Comment: What is this? `,doc}` It has no place in the statement and is causing the error. Not really sure you you understand what this is supposed to do, or otherwise it's unclear what you "think" you want this to do. So either that's a typo you missed or you don't understand the statement.

Comment: then how the doc will get inserted, if it is not present and "es_mysql_id" will have value of serial_number. if updated no need to change "es_mysql_id"

Comment: Dude. You just cannot mix `$setOnInsert` with a "literal" object. You can specify all other keys via `$set`, but it's all or nothing. Supplying a plain object with no modifier is only valid for `replaceOne()`